# Compilation of Elyra-Pipelines to Tekton based Kubeflow fails

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-lab, kubeflow-pipelines, tekton, elyra

I've installed a kubernetes cluster running kubeflow pipelines based on tekton on top of [KIND](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) using the following [instructions](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfp-tekton/blob/master/guides/kfp_tekton_install.md#standalone-kubeflow-pipelines-with-tekton-backend-deployment)

Now I'm getting the following error message from the Elyra pipelines editor. Running against an argo based kfp cluster works fine.

Is the kfp compiler somehow not supporting tekton? Can someone please shine some light on this?

HTTP response body:

```
{"error_message":"Error creating pipeline: Create pipeline failed: 
Failed to get parameters from the pipelineRun: Invalid input error: 
Unsupported argo version. 
Expected: tekton.dev/v1beta1.
Received: argoproj.io/v1alpha1",
"error_details":"Error creating pipeline: Create pipeline failed: 
Failed to get parameters from the pipelineRun: Invalid input error: 
Unsupported argo version. Expected: tekton.dev/v1beta1. 
Received: argoproj.io/v1alpha1"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different aspects to consider here:

There is a need to perform a custom deployment to enable Kubeflow Pipelines to integrate/use a Tekton environment. As you mentioned the steps are described [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfp-tekton/blob/master/guides/kfp_tekton_install.md#standalone-kubeflow-pipelines-with-tekton-backend-deployment).

As for Elyra support, Elyra recent releases starting with Elyra 2.x has incorporated support for KFP using Tekton and further documentation is available in the [Elyra user guide](https://elyra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/runtime-conf.html#kubeflow-pipelines-engine-engine)

If you are still using Elyra 1.x or lower, the below still applies:

Now, related to compiling and executing the Kubeflow Pipeline on a Tekton environment, Elyra is currently using the KFP SDK python package and the regular compiler to compile and generate the default ARGO YAML (see code [here](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/blob/9de4c89a0e35f13dedd671ce36cb3f6286593fea/elyra/pipeline/processor_kfp.py#L71)). In order to support Tekton, we will need to use a different python package (kfp-tekton==0.3.0) and there is also a need for a different code path during compilation (see [example](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfp-tekton/tree/master/guides/kfp-user-guide#1-compile-pipelines-using-the-kfp_tektoncompilertektoncompiler-in-python)).

Another aspect is that it seems that there are some incompatibilities between the two pipelines as described in the [migration path](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfp-tekton/tree/master/guides/kfp-user-guide#migration-from-argo-backend).

Regarding support, the [Elyra project](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra) would welcome contributions.

Comment: fixed in https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/pull/1239

Answer (score 0):

As of now the Tekton compiler is in a separate package. You can install it with `pip install kfp-tekton==0.3.0` for kubeflow 1.2 . [Here](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfp-tekton/tree/master/guides/kfp-user-guide) is the user guide

Currently, Elyra doesn't support compiling for kfp-tekton, only kfp-argo

There is an open [Issue](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/issues/1222) on that with the Elyra team